# printf() is printing a character after the terminating character in C, how do I fix this?

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I have a for loop in randomString() that puts a random character into the first x indexes of a string, where x < the string length. I then add a '\0' to the string and print it with printf() but it prints 1 more character than x and that character is always the same, I don't know why.

This is the code that I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NELEMS(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])
#define MAX_LENGTH 25

void randomChar();
void randomString();

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int points = 0;

    randomString(&points, 3);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void randomString(int *points, int length)
{    
    char input[MAX_LENGTH], output[MAX_LENGTH];
    do
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < length && i < NELEMS(output)-1; i++)
            output[i] = (char)(rand() % 26 + 97);
        output[i+1] = '\0';
        //output[i+2] = '\0';

        // for (int i = 0; i < NELEMS(output)-1; i++)
        //     output[i] = i < length ? (char)(rand() % 26 + 97) : '\0';

        
        printf("You have %d points, type %s:\n", *points, output);
        scanf("%s", &input);

        strcmp(input, output) == 0 ? *(points)++ : *(points)--;        
        getchar();
    } while (input[0] != '@');
}
```

I have been trying this function with a length of 3 and get a result:

```
You have 0 points, type opc♦:
a
You have 0 points, type lbu♦:
a
You have 14488832 points, type wal♦:
```

using `output[i+1] = '\0'` and `output[i+2] = '\0'` don't fix anything
the commented out for loop works but I don't know why the first one isn't working

Do you know why its printing an extra character?

oh and if you know why 14488832 appears in the output i'd like to know that aswell.

EDIT:

dbush fixed the pointer bug with (*points)++ instead of *(points)++ but the first bug with printing another character after the 3 letter string like the following is still there:

```
You have 0 points, type opc♦:
a
You have 0 points, type lbu♦:
```

Comment: Use `output[length] = '\0';` and also `*points = strcmp(input, output) == 0 ? *points + 1 : *points - 1;`

Comment: `int points;` gives you a single integer.  `&points` is the address of that single integer. In `randomString`, when you increment `points` you are effectively trying to write to the 2nd integer of the 1 integer that you had available.  That is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ask a single question only.  Your second question is unrelated to the title, and a separate issue.  By posting two questions in one, you require any answerer to cover both issues before an answer is acceptable.  If you had two separate answers answering different parts, you could not accept both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're building the string:

```
    for (i = 0; i < length && i < NELEMS(output)-1; i++)
        output[i] = (char)(rand() % 26 + 97);
    output[i+1] = '\0';
```

A `for` loop performs the increment step *first*, then checks the condition.  This means that `i` has been incremented one more time when the loop exits, so using `i+1` as the loop index for the terminating character skips one.  You need to use `i` instead:

```
    output[i] = '\0';
```

As for the strange numbers in the output here's your problem:

```
strcmp(input, output) == 0 ? *(points)++ : *(points)--;
```

You're incrementing / decrementing the pointer `points` instead what it points to.  As a result, you're stepping on memory you shouldn't be which triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To increment / decrement what `points` points to, move the parenthesis to dereference first.

```
strcmp(input, output) == 0 ? (*points)++ : (*points)--;
```

Comment: I just changed that and it fixed the issue with the points but it still prints the diamonds like this: "You have 0 points, type gfk♦:"

Comment: @Toby See my edit.  `i` has already been incremented when the loop exits.

Comment: The question was (primarily) about the extra character (per the title)  You might do better to swap this around to offer an answer to the primary question first.  The OP asks about the other issue as an aside and would be advised to stick to the one question per post rule

Answer (score 0):

```c
output[i+1] = '\0';
```

should be

```c
output[i] = '\0';
```

Don't forget that `i` was incremented before the last loop condition check.

---

Additionally, `++` and `--` have higher precedence than `*`, so

```c
strcmp(input, output) == 0 ? *(points)++ : *(points)--;
```

means

```c
strcmp(input, output) == 0 ? *(points++) : *(points--);
```

but you want

```c
strcmp(input, output) == 0 ? (*points)++ : (*points)--;
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop terminates whe `i == length`, so `output[i+1] = '\0'` is out by one, and should be;

```
output[i] = '\0' ;
```

or just:

```
output[length] = '\0' ;
```

I would suggest the latter since it allows the localisation of `i` to jest the loop:

```
for( int i = 0; 
     i < length && i < NELEMS(output)-1; 
     i++)
{
    output[i] = (char)(rand() % 26 + 97);
}

output[length] = '\0' ;
```